# In Hadoop, the node get wrong IP address

Tags: hadoop

I install Hadoop on a single machine with two VMs(x1 & x2), and set x1(10.42.0.70) as namenode and datanode, x2(10.42.0.71) as the only datanode. When I start Hadoop. I found that Hadoop assign x1 and x2 with the wrong IP address. x1 and x2 both have IP address 127.0.1.1. I want to know how Hadoop finds an IP address for a node from the hostname and where is the problem. Thanks for any tips.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y40cv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXP4I.png)

Comment: Can you paste contents of your /etc/hosts of the VMs ?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.1.1 is a loopback interface. Can you paste contents of your /etc/hosts file?

Additionally check this out: https://serverfault.com/questions/424232/how-does-hadoop-decide-what-its-nodes-hostnames-are

Comment: my computer is in my department LAN, I have set the nameserver. at first there is one line `127.0.0.1  localhost` in /etc/hosts ,  then i add `10.42.0.70  x1` and `10.42.0.71  x2`  it does not work

Comment: Can you run ip addr on one of the VM's and past the output?

Comment: `hduser@student17-x1:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: `
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:ae:9b:d1:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.70/23 brd 255.255.254.0 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::223:aeff:fe9b:d146/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: You can try commenting out 127.0.1.1 in your /etc/hosts leaving only 127.0.0.1 and IP's of the VM's

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: One other place where you can check is the files: $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/slaves and $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/masters

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found out that the cause was a way how nodes connect to each other. A datanode was configured to connect to local namenode by using localhost as an address (`hdfs://localhost:9000` in my case). It seems that namenode uses such connection to resolve datanode address as `127.0.1.1`

Following should help, add to `core-size.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.42.0.70:9000</value>
</property>
```